# how to make toolbar button bigger than toolbar?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitoolbar

I was wondering how I would go about making a toolbar item (with image) that is taller than the actual toolbar is? In this example the photo button is bigger than the toolbar:  [image]

Whenever I try adding an image to a toolbar item it just stretches or shrinks it until it fits the button.

Anyone know how to do this? If you can do this with a tab-bar that would also be fine.

Thanks!

Comment: These are probably helpful: [link 1](http://fotovidia.com/2012/02/how-to-add-a-featured-center-button-to-uitoolbar-like-fotovidia/) – [link 2](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/eetoolbarcenterbutton) – [link 3](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/)

Answer (score 1):

This is not built-in functionality - you will either need to hack the view hierarchy of a `UITabBar` or `UIToolBar` to get what you want or write your own equivalent view. Whilst the former approach may be faster, the latter is probably better because messing with the built-in views like that can introduce significant problems should Apple change how they work in future OS releases.

Answer (score 1):

This is a custom toolbar and that's how it can be done in the best way I think.
Create an image of a tool bar, create three buttons and make one of them bigger and that should do it.

Answer (score -1):

The above just looks like a graphic super-imposed over the toolbar. Simply add it to the `window` so it will stay on top of everything.

Comment: Autorotation is anyway unusual with tab bars. So maybe not so bad an idea.

Comment: Of course, but it is still less common. Also, you *can* make a superimposed image rotate with extra code in the autorotate callbacks.